# python similar keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have dictionary: `dict = {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3, key1:value4, key2:value5, key3:value6}`

if i print keys from dictionary

```
def my_func():
    for key in dict:
        print(key)
```

it print only last 3 keys:
for example:

```
   key1
   key2
   key3
```

but keys in dictionary can be same.
Can you explain me why? if the key is the same, how to print like this:

```
key2:value2,value5
```

if it is possible.
thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary

Comment: `dict = {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3, key1:value4, key2:value5, key3:value6}` => data is lost as soon as you declared it.

Comment: have a look at `collections.defaultdict` https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a result like `key2:value2,value5`, you can use a `collections.defaultdict`.

Here's the example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Comment: thank you for resolution :-)

Answer (score 0):

The keys in the dictionary cannot be the same. Statement `key1:value4`, effectively translates too:

```
x = {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3}
x[key1] = value4
```

So your just overwriting the previous value. To have the desired effect you should implement a custom dict that stores the values in a list, and then some custom method to clear the list assuming that evey statement like `x[key1] = value1` appends the value and does not replace it.

```
    class CustomDictOne(dict):
       def __init__(self):
          self._mydict = defaultdict(lambda:[])

       def __setitem__(self, key, item):
           self._mydict[key].append(item)

        def clear(self,key)
           self._mydict[key] = []

        def __getitem__(self, key):
           return self._mydict[key]
```

If you use a custom field name like I did `_mydict` you should also re-implement all the other methods: